# Is there a way to get the SKProduct from an SKPayment in the StoreKit API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

Given an `SKPaymentTransaction` is there a way to get the `SKProduct`?

I'm trying to implement a generic `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` that will allow my app to be notified of all in-app purchases that occur. I have implemented the `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` interface, and I am getting the `paymentQueue: updatedTransactions:` callback firing correctly. In my callback I have access to the `SKPaymentTransaction` object, and from there I can get the `SKPayment` object. From the payment I cannot find a way to get the `SKProduct` though.

This is frustrating since the `SKPayment` must have been created using the `SKProduct`, but the interface only allows the user to get the `productIdentifier`. To create an SKPayment

Really, I want to get access to the cost, quantity, and local currency that was spent, and these are properties of the `SKProduct`.

The only way I can see to do this is to swizzle [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:]` and intercept payment creation, which is an awful prospect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think it is possible right now to get that information from the the SKPaymentTransaction or its SKPayment object.

You could query this information though by setting up a SKProductRequest with one or more product identifiers.  The response is handled by [productsRequest:didReceiveResponse](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProductsRequestDelegate/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SKProductsRequestDelegate/productsRequest%3adidReceiveResponse%3a).

Apple's documentation has a pretty good example of how to do it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/ShowUI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW9).

Comment: Thanks. If I do fire off an SKProductRequest, my app will be doing a (second) network request to Apple to get this data, when the app will have had to do one already to initiate the whole process.

Comment: Right.  Maybe some day Apple will return the SKProduct as a part of the SKPayment.  I just do this request right at start up and keep the information but I only have a few ids so that works in my case.

Answer (score 9):

> Given an SKPaymentTransaction is there a way to get the SKProduct?

You could get the productIdentifier from the transaction object from which you can get the product info if you have an array of SKProducts by looking up the array for productIdentifier,

```
transaction.payment.productIdentifier
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem, too.  (I wanted to get the product's price upon successful purchase.)  My solution is to store the each `SKProduct` in a `Dictionary`, using the `productIdentifier` as the key.  Here's the gist of my implementation (in Swift 3):

Declare the dictionary as a property in your class:

```swift
fileprivate var products = Dictionary<String, SKProduct>()
```

Store products in the dictionary when the `productsRequest(_:didReceive:)` callback function of `SKProductsRequestDelegate` is called:

```swift
extension PurchaseManager: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        for product in response.products {
            products[product.productIdentifier] = product
        }
    }
}
```

When the `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)` callback function of `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` is called, retrieve the product from the dictionary:

```swift
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        let product = products[transaction.payment.productIdentifier]
        let price = product?.price
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this only works to an extent. The thing is once you submit a product in payment queue, the app may crash or get killed or whatever but Apple will still keep the `SKProduct` in the payment queue until it is marked finished by your app. Whenever your app launches and registers an observer, `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)` will get called but this time your dictionary will be empty cause it did not get a chance to repopulate and then you lost all that data. So I think you need to save `SKProduct` on disc that persists (e.g. CoreData) across app launch cycles.